# Reading of Spring balance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

I was wondering what would be the reading of a spring balance if it is placed horizontally on a table with two blocks attached to it at the either end and hanging vertically downwards ??
Will that reading depend on whether the blocks are of equal weight or not  .

For ex - If i have two blocks of of 1 Kg each hanging from both the ends, let the reading be **x**. **CASE I:** if i have two blocks of 1 kg and 2kg respectively how will the reading change assuming that  the 1Kg block is always attached to the hook of the spring balance ?**CASE 2:** if i have block of 0.5 Kg and 1kg , ( 1kg is attached to the hook) will the reading decrease or increase?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of the end to which a block I attached. The reading of the spring balance will always be equal to the tension in the spring balance.

When blocks attached are of equal masses the tension would be equal to the weight of one block.

In case of unequal masses attached on either ends, the masses will undergo acceleration and you can calculate the tension using Newton's Third Law.